# Generate token for Artifactory user

Tags: artifactory

I try to generate an access token for an Artifactory user using this command:

```
curl -u<user>:<password> -XPOST https://<server_url>/artifactory/api/security/token
```

And I get following error:

```
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 500,
    "message" : "The @FormParam is utilized when the content type of the request entity is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  } ]
}
```

I tried as password the login password of the user, the API key and the Encrypted Password. Each time I got the same result.

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Comment: That sounds like curl isn't generating a POST body from that command and hence not the request body content type it expects. Do you need to post any parameters with the token create request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's the documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-CreateToken). You're missing two mandatory parameters:

- username - must be your username unless you're an admin
- scope - permissions you're requesting, e.g. "scope=member-of-groups:readers"

i.e. you need:

```
curl -u<user>:<password> -XPOST https://<server_url>/artifactory/api/security/token
     -d "username=<user>" -d "scope=member-of-groups:readers"
```

The specific error is because you're not passing any parameters at all. curl is therefore not generating a request body and hence it is not including a 'Content-Type' header in the request, and the server is reporting that it only knows how to pass arguments to the REST API from a POSTed form.

Comment: The mandatory parameters were missing, thank you very much for the help!